# z-index doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, css, z-index

Actually i use Internet Explorer 10 and see some problems with my code , this code works fine in all browsers and no have problems only give me problem IE

**My Code :**

```
<style>
#web_header_sub_data
{
top:-60px;
position:relative;
width:980px;
height:96px;
margin:auto;
z-index:1;
}


#login_s_window_background
{
top:1px;    
position:absolute;
position:fixed;
left:50%;
margin-left:-50%;
width:100%;
height:150%;
background-color:#111111;
z-index:9;
background:rgb(17,17,17,0.7);
background:rgba(17,17,17,0.7);
}

</style>




<div id="web_header_sub_data">
<div id="login_s_window_background"></div>
</div>
```

In all browsers i see the div called login_s_window_background show over all divs and no have problem and only with Internet Explorer see bad and under other divs , how you see , the z-index it´s more high of other div must show over the other divs

I don´t understand why no works fine if in all browsers it´s ok

Howewer exits some fix for this if the response it´s yes please tell me how i can fix it

Thank´s , regards

Answer (score 0):

You have overwritten rules. Try to replace the div properties with these ones:

```
#login_s_window_background
{
   top:0;
   position:fixed;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   background-color:#111111;
   z-index:9;
   background:rgba(17,17,17,0.7);
}
```

Comment: This no works , sorry , regards this background use this 2 positions and works in all browsers but no inside Internet Explorer and with this change no works also , problem it´s z-index ignored by IE

Answer (score 0):

> the z-index it´s more high of other div must show over the other divs

This is not correct - z-index is only valid within the same positioning context. A new positioning context is started by an element that has a `position` value of `fixed`, `relative` or `absolute`. A descendant element of such an element can never 'break out' of the parent's Z-index within its own positioning context.

Imagine:

```
<div id="a" style="z-index:1">
    <div id="b" style="z-index:4">
</div>
<div id="c" style="z-index:2">
    <div id="d" style="z-index:3">
</div>
```

And a CSS rule of `div { position:absolute }`: in this case both divs `c` and `d` would still be on top of `b` because `c` is already on top of `a`, and `d` as such automatically is as well.

Since this invalidates your base claim, your whole Z-index structure is probably messed up, and this is what most probably causes your rendering issues.

IE10 should handle all Z-indexing perfectly fine according to standards if set up correctly, and *using an HTML5 or other correctly formatted modern doctype*. Do double check that you didn't put it in quirks mode.